# How can I create extension method for Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes

Tags: c#

I have this code to track errors but only for live

```
Crashes.TrackError(ex);
```

I don't want to be sending crashes on development so I have this

```
if (!Debugger.IsAttached) Crashes.TrackError(ex);
```

but the if condition is redundant so I wanted to create an extension method like

```
Crashes.TrackErrorLive(ex);
```

I tried the following code but it's not working... I've also read that extension method requires an instance

```
public static void TrackErrorLive(this Crashes crashes, Exception ex)
        {
            if (!Debugger.IsAttached) Crashes.TrackError(ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create an extension method for static class. But you can create your own static class with method needed:

```
public static class CrashesExtensions
{
    public static void TrackErrorLive(Exception ex)
    {
        if (!Debugger.IsAttached) Crashes.TrackError(ex);
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
CrashesExtensions.TrackErrorLive(ex);
```